# Rearranging a string to be a palindrome

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the problem of: ***Given an array of strings with only lower case letters, make a function that returns an array of those same strings, but each string has its letters rearranged such that it becomes a palindrome (if not possible then return -1).***  I'm a bit stuck on how I should be rearranging the letters.

`let arr = ["hello", "racecra"]`;

I created a function to first check *if* a word is a palindrome :

```
function isPalindrome(arr) {
     let obj = {};

      for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {

             if (obj[arr[x]]) {
                obj[arr[x]] += 1;
             } else {
                obj[arr[x]] = 1;
             }

      }

      let countOdd = 0;
      let countEven = 0; 
 
      for (let x of Object.values(obj)) {
           if (x % 2 == 0) {
              countEven += 1;
          } else {
               countOdd += 1;
          }

      }
      return countOdd == 1 ? true : false

}
```

then I plan to loop through the words

```
let emptyArr = [];

for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
     if (isPalindrome(arr[x]) {
        // not sure what to do here.  I know the word is a palindrome but not sure how to sort the order of the word in the palindrome form. 
     } else {
        emptyArr.push(-1);
     }
}

return emptyArr;
```

Comment: Sort the characters of the string. it can be rearranged into a palindrome if there are an even number of each character, except there can be one singular character (this will go into the middle of the result string). Then just build up the string by appending one of each pair at the beginning and end.

Comment: And one more thing from more side: don't do this `return countOdd == 1 ? true : false`. Result of `===` operation is always boolean, there's no need for additional ternary there.

Comment: ah redundant, yes...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely: you don't need your words to be palindromes, you need them to be **rearrangeable** as palindromes ("palindrome-candidates"). Now, a word is a palindrome-candidate if all of its letters but one can be counted by an even number (2, 4, 6 etc.)

For example, this...

```
hollo
```

... is NOT a palindrome, but can become one, as there's 2 'o', 2 'l' and just one 'h' in it. To rearrange, you just move 'h' in the middle, then just place 'o' and 'l' before and after it:

```
l -> o -> h <- o <- l
```

So start with splitting each of your words by characters, then either count those characters or just sort them (as @Barmar suggested). If they satisfy the condition, rearrange the letters following the approach given; if not, return null (or any other special value clearly distinguishable from the rest) immediately.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```js
function rearrangeAsPalindrome(word) {
  if (word.length === 1) return word; // easy win first

  const charCounter = word.split('').reduce((counter, ch) => ({
    ...counter,
    [ch]: (counter[ch] || 0) + 1
  }), {});

  const parts = ['', '', '']; // left, middle, right 

  const entries = Object.entries(charCounter);
  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
    const [char, counter] = entries[i];
    if (counter % 2) { // odd
      if (parts[1] !== '') return null;
      // one odd is already here, eject! eject!

      parts[1] = char.repeat(counter);
    } 
    else { // even
      const half = counter / 2;
      parts[0] = char.repeat(half) + parts[0];
      parts[2] += char.repeat(half);
    }
  }

  return parts.join('');
}

console.log(rearrangeAsPalindrome('racarrrac')); // crraaarrc
console.log(rearrangeAsPalindrome('aabbcc')); // cbaabc
console.log(rearrangeAsPalindrome('hollo')); // lohol
console.log(rearrangeAsPalindrome('hello')); // null
```

This function returns `null` (and does it early) when it realizes the word given cannot be rearranged as a palindrome - or an actual palindrome if it is possible.

Comment: thank you.  Wouldn't the logic still need to be split in that you first have a function to determine _if_ it can be a palindrome.  Then separately, another function to rearrange the word into a palindrome form.
If I don't know beforehand that a word can be a palindrome, then how can I determine that by sorting it and appending each letter at the beginning/end?

Comment: @ddjk That's one way to do that, but actually I think there'll be some overlap. The way I suggested has two things done in one function (counting characters is the first step, arranging them in a palindrome is the second one), but that's just for illustration purposes; you can extract charCounting as a separate function.

Comment: oh wow ok, this makes a lot more sense after looking at the example you coded.  Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

This can help

"How to generate distinct palindromes from a string in JavaScript"

https://medium.com/@bibinjaimon/how-to-generate-distinct-palindromes-from-a-string-in-javascript-6763940f5138